# .NET portal to "host" multiple .NET applications - How should I set up roles and permissions?

Tags: .net, membership

I'd like to build a .NET web portal to hold multiple .NET applications.  However, I'd like it to only show those apps that are available to the logged in user.

How would you do this?

Comment: Perhaps you'll store the users, applications, the roles and permissions in a database, right? If so, please give more details in the question or let us know if you have other ways in mind.

Comment: Yes, the users, roles and permissions would be stored in the database.  It would be nice to control it in AD, but I can't guarantee the users would be only internal to our company